# Google API console

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How i can use google api console for my project ?

My project uses static map api and I have listened that by using API console, i can see my usage limits but don't know how I can use it ?

Comment: More info required. i.e. language + purpose

Comment: for static map api, only url is required, so i think it is independent of the language. But for your reference, i am using java script. purpose i have already written that i want to see my map usage

Answer (score 2):

You can sign up for an API key using the Google Developer Console at:

**https://code.google.com/apis/console**

*However*, for the time being Static Maps API usage does not show up in the console.

Comment: so how can i measure static map uage ?

Comment: the console give me an API key, that i think i  have to send in the key parameter. But when i send wrong key, i also get the response. so not able to verify that what i am doing is correct or not

Comment: You'll have to wait until metrics for Static Maps show up in the console.  Not yet available.